# Versioning, how to build various assembly versions with unique publicKeyTokens?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I work on a legacy project and have to support 8 different versions of the same dll. I have access to the library source, so I can build these dll's myself.

The dll's are strongly signed, and each has it's own version number 3.6.0.0, 3.7.0.1, etc.

However, each dll has the same publicKeyToken. This is frustrating, because I get build warnings:

> No way to resolve conflict between "Test.Core, Version=9.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c6699d902bca3abc" and "Test.Core,
>   Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c6699d902bca3abc".
>   Choosing "Test.Core, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c6699d902bca3abc" arbitrarily.

any suggestions to fix this? How can I get unique key tokens?

Comment: How do you reference your assemblies? And did you set *Specific Version* to `True` on the properties tab of the reference?

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly the problem. Specific version uses the publicKeyToken to determine which assembly to use. If I set specific version to false, the build warning doesn't occure. I want to know how to build a new version of the assembly with a new keyToken

Comment: So I have assembly version 7.4.0.0, and version 9.0.0.0. But after building them both have the same keytoken. How can I make each one unique?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after lots of searching and trying various configurations I must conclude this cannot be solved in any way.

It is not even possible to suppress the buildwarning :s [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93c3b258-0ca6-46c2-aca3-36b51c304e13/extern-alias-doesnt-suppress-msb3243-and-msb3247?forum=msbuild)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using custom configurations set by conditions. Consider a design in which each configuration has a reference to a different output path.

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug_TestCore740'">
    <Reference Include="Test.Core, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c6699d902bca3abc, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <HintPath>..\Test.Core\$(Configuration)\Test.Core.dll</HintPath>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug_TestCore900'">
    <Reference Include="Test.Core, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c6699d902bca3abc, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <HintPath>..\Test.Core\$(Configuration)\Test.Core.dll</HintPath>
  </ItemGroup>
```